# How to remove Grafana data periodically?

Tags: grafana

I have deployed Grafana monitoring system, it saves the databases on "/home/user/data" directory, the problem is that the data persists for ever so the filesystem is full usage and I would like to remove this data, for example weekly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not say what data you would like to remove or what is generating all the data (it is logs?). It seems strange to just delete data from your database? Will your users not miss their dashboards?

I am going to assume you want to remove data from the database. There are a few ways to do this.

1. Save a clean copy of the Sqlite database and then replace the database file once a week. This will lose all your data.
2. For most data saved in the database, you could use the Grafana API to remove data.

   An example, would be to [remove dashboards](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/#delete-dashboard). With curl and basic auth:

   `curl -X DELETE http://admin:admin@localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db/testdash`
3. Use the [sqlite cli](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) to write sql queries to delete data directly.

Comment: My problem is that I am using Grafana with Prometheus, and they save old data and graphics, maybe I am not right and the problem is Prometheus. I will accept your answer becouse you have answered the question, and maybe I am confused.

Comment: Grafana is a frontend so it does not save data from Prometheus, it just queries from it and then graphs it. The data that Grafana saves is its own data like users, dashboards, data sources and alert data. It does not grow every week unless users are adding lots of dashboards, data sources etc. It could be Grafana logs, how big are the log files in the /var/log/grafana directory(or wherever the log files are)?

Comment: I thought it was so, but when I saw that the filesystem increased a lot I confused, and maybe it would only about Prometheus :) Really thankss